# Update query using cross join

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that's a dictionary of words you might find in a company name, and their synonyms. I want to use this to standardize the names in another table. For example, "WIDGET COMPANY INCORPORATED" would be standardized to "WIDGET CO INC". I thought it would be as simple as the below cross join, but it seems to only run for the first synonym in the list, rather than the entire list. Am I going about this the wrong way? I was going to try to do it in SSIS instead if I can't figure this out, but I think that would be over-complicating what should be a relatively simple task... of course, I realize since this is a cross join, we're talking about a lot of rows - 50 million, to be precise...

```
update [dbo].[Company addresses]
set [Name 1 syn] = replace(a.[Name 1 syn], ' ' + b.[Synonym] + ' ', ' ' + b.[Base] + ' ')
from [dbo].[Company addresses] a
cross join dbo.Synonyms b
```

Comment: Yes. An `UPDATE` only runs once per target row even if there are many on the other side of the join. The plan probably has an `ANY` aggregate to pick one out of the many possible.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do. Could you provide some table structure and sample data and sample results.

Comment: @HLGEM - If `[Company addresses].Name` is `1 the street, London` and they have two synonym rows `street -> road` and `London -> Big City` I think the intention is to run each replace in turn over all the synonyms so final result =  `1 the road, Big City`

Comment: That's right, thanks Martin. It seems you're right - it only runs once per target row... I'm currently looking into trying to do it with a WHILE loop, per this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1207630.aspx . I still wish there was a simpler way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
DECLARE @RC int = 1;

WHILE @RC > 0
BEGIN
  update [dbo].[Company addresses]
  set [Name 1 syn] = replace(a.[Name 1 syn], ' ' + b.[Synonym] + ' ', ' ' + b.[Base] + ' ')
  from [dbo].[Company addresses] a
  inner join dbo.Synonyms b on a.[Name 1 syn] LIKE '% ' + b.[Synonym] + ' %';

  SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Comment: Warning, to avoid infinite loops you have to make sure you don't have cycles in your Synonyms table (like 'abc' => 'abc'; or both 'abc' => 'xyz' and 'xyz' = 'abc', etc.)

Comment: Wow, perfect, thanks! I had figured out a way to do it but your way is much simpler and faster. I don't know why I didn't think of using a "LIKE" statement instead of trying to run the replace on every single combination of rows in both tables...

Comment: No problem.  It will still scan both tables for each pass and evaluate the LIKE, but will only perform updates on rows that need them. It's much better to let SQL Server process them as sets than to loop through rows yourself (if you can manage it).