# SQL SERVER How to update duplicate records with a SET UPDATE instead of using a CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best practice for iterating through a result set that has duplicate ID's in SQL Server?
I am currently using a CURSOR to loop over 40000 records in a stored procedure. Execution time for the stored procedure
can be up to an hour in my lower environments.

Here is an example of the data from my SELECT.

| ID | CodeValue |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | HI |
| 123456 | OHI |
| 123456 | OI |
| 123456 | SLI |
| 123456 | VI |
| 123456 | MD |
| 987654 | OI |
| 876543 | MD |

I would like to use a SET Operation to update my table with every row brought back in the SELECT but the SET excludes the duplicates.
So in other words, I need to loop through and UPDATE my table with all the records.
The records contain duplicate ID's but each row is different based upon the 2nd CodeValue column.

Below when using the SET operation my code only picks up the first of the 6 records with the same ID

| ID | CodeValue |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | HI |
| 987654 | OI |
| 876543 | MD |

How can I write my SET operation to select all the records?
Here is the SELECT example for the data set.

```
SELECT ID, CodeValue into #tempTable
FROM ExtractA
UNION
SELECT ID, CodeValue
FROM ExtractB 
WHERE Indicator = 0
```

Here is the SET UPDATE example:

```
    UPDATE ta
        ,ta.[HI] =
            CASE
                WHEN  t.CodeValue = 'HI' THEN 1 
                else ta.[HI]
            END 
        ,ta.[MD] =
            CASE
                WHEN t.CodeValue = 'MD' THEN 1 
                ELSE ta.[MD]
            END
        ,ta.[OHI] =
            CASE
                WHEN t.CodeValue = 'OHI'  THEN 1 
                ELSE ta.[OHI]
            END 
        ,ta.[OI] =
            CASE
                WHEN t.CodeValue = 'OI' THEN 1 
                ELSE ta.[OI]
            END     
        ,ta.[SLI] =
            CASE
                WHEN t.CodeValue = 'SLI'  THEN 1 
                ELSE ta.[SLI]
            END
        ,ta.[VI] =
            CASE
                WHEN t.CodeValue = 'VI'  THEN 1                     
                ELSE  ta.[VI]
            END         
    FROM [dbo].[tableA] ta 
    JOIN #tempTable t 
        on ta.ID = t.ID
    WHERE ta.FiscalYear = @piFiscalYear
```

Comment: I have *assumed* SQL Server here, however, if you are using something else that uses Transact-SQL, such as Sybase or Azure Synapse, please [edit] your question to correct the tags.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't first do `ALTER TABLE tblName ADD COLUMN RowId int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` and _then_ use that to discriminate rows?

Comment: It looks as though you might pivot on CodeValue, making HI, MD... align with their respective columns, and if so, match on ID and it would be set based.

Comment: Hi Dia I would like to do that but I can't alter my primary table.  I will have one row with the uniqueID that has multiple updates to several t.CodeValue columns.

Comment: @oglester can you give me an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254228/update-query-using-cross-join

Comment: I may be missing something, but could you just put the CodeValue column as a second predicate on the join: `JOIN #tempTable t ON ta.ID = t.ID AND ta.CodeValue = t.CodeValue`? Not sure if both tables uniquely have that value.

Comment: Hi @JoeS no that doesn't work in this case.  I wish it was that easy.  Both tables don't have that unique value.

Comment: I just looked back at the code and saw that the CodeValue field is from table t, not ta. That is unfortunate. I believe @oglester may be on the right track. I will try to come up with an example. Can you provide some sample data for tableA? That would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt at producing the results you are looking for. This solution assumes that you have a finite set of CodeValue entries. If they are variable or numerous, this may not work for you.

The `#pivotTable` temp table is what @oglester was referring to. It transposes the data so instead of having multiple records per ID, it becomes one record per ID.

Below the code is the `#tableA` output before and after the update.

```
DECLARE @piFiscalYear SMALLINT = 2022;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTable;
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , CodeValue VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tempTable (ID, CodeValue) VALUES
    (123456, 'HI'),
    (123456, 'OHI'),
    (123456, 'OI'),
    (123456, 'SLI'),
    (123456, 'VI'),
    (123456, 'MD'),
    (987654, 'OI'),
    (876543, 'MD');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tableA;
CREATE TABLE #tableA
(
    ID INT NOT NULL
    , FiscalYear SMALLINT NOT NULL
    , [HI] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , [OHI] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , [OI] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , [SLI] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , [VI] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , [MD] VARCHAR(3) NULL
    , AnotherColumn VARCHAR(15) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tableA
    (
        ID
        , FiscalYear
        , [HI], [OHI], [OI], [SLI], [VI], [MD]
        , AnotherColumn
    )
VALUES
    (123456, 2022, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Some data'),
    (987654, 2022, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'More data'),
    (876543, 2022, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'So much data'),
    (123456, 2021, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Old data'),
    (987654, 2000, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Really old data'),
    (876543, 1901, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Just for fun');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #pivotTable;
SELECT
    ID, [HI], [OHI], [OI], [SLI], [VI], [MD]
INTO #pivotTable
FROM
    (SELECT ID, CodeValue FROM #tempTable) t
    PIVOT (COUNT(CodeValue) FOR CodeValue IN ([HI],[OHI],[OI],[SLI],[VI],[MD])
    ) AS pvt;

SELECT * FROM #tableA;

UPDATE ta
    SET [HI] = pvt.[HI],
        [OHI] = pvt.[OHI],
        [OI] = pvt.[OI],
        [SLI] = pvt.[SLI],
        [VI] = pvt.[VI],
        [MD] = pvt.[MD]
FROM
    #tableA ta
    INNER JOIN #pivotTable pvt
        ON ta.ID = pvt.ID
WHERE
    ta.FiscalYear = @piFiscalYear;

SELECT * FROM #tableA;
```

### Before the update:

| ID | FiscalYear | HI | OHI | OI | SLI | VI | MD | AnotherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2022 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Some data |
| 987654 | 2022 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | More data |
| 876543 | 2022 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | So much data |
| 123456 | 2021 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Old data |
| 987654 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Really old data |
| 876543 | 1901 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Just for fun |

### After the update:

| ID | FiscalYear | HI | OHI | OI | SLI | VI | MD | AnotherColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Some data |
| 987654 | 2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | More data |
| 876543 | 2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | So much data |
| 123456 | 2021 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Old data |
| 987654 | 2000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Really old data |
| 876543 | 1901 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Just for fun |

Comment: Exactly, and that may be how the data got that way in the first place.

Comment: @Joe S this is great.  It meets my needs.  I don't have enough point to cast a vote but I upvote here if that helps!  Thanks

Comment: I am glad it helped you out! Rather than voting, I believe it would be more helpful to accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons. This helps others find questions with acceptable answers when searching, and it provides reputation to both parties. You do not need a certain reputation to accept an answer.